# Action masking for continuous action space in reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, policy-gradient-descent, sac

Is there a way to model action masking for continuous action spaces? I want to model economic problems with reinforcement learning. These problems often have continuous action and state spaces. In addition, the state often influences what actions are possible and, thus, the allowed actions change from step to step.

Simple example:

The agent has a wealth (continuous state) and decides about spending (continuous action). The next periods is then wealth minus spending. But he is restricted by the budget constraint. He is not allowed to spend more than his wealth. What is the best way to model this?

What I tried:
For discrete actions it is possible to use [action masking](https://towardsdatascience.com/action-masking-with-rllib-5e4bec5e7505). So in each time step, I provided the agent with information which action is allowed and which not. I also tried to do it with contiuous action space by providing lower and upper bound on allowed actions and clip the actions smapled from actor network (e.g. DDPG).

I am wondering if this is a valid thing to do (it works in a simple toy model) because I did not find any RL library that implements this. Or is there a smarter way/best practice to include the information about allowed actions to the agent?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you manage to modify the NN to mask the action space ? I'm curious about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. I've looked into masked actions and found two possible approaches: give a negative reward when trying to take an invalid action (without letting the environment evolve), or dive deeper into the neural network code and let the neural network output only valid actions.
I've always considered this last approach as the most efficient, and your approach of introducing boundaries seems very similar to it. So as long as this is the type of mask (boundaries) you are looking for, I think you are good to go.